# GET request for openweather API not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, openweathermap

I'm making a weather app that uses geolocation, but also search.

The function for geolocation is working, but user search is failing; the error in the console is: GET {api url} 404 (Not Found).

First, the function that does NOT work:

```
    function getWeatherWithUserInput() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   var location = $("#location").val().trim();
   var widget = Mixcloud.PlayerWidget(document.getElementById('my-widget-iframe'));

   var weatherCSQueryURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + "=&appid=" + WeatherAPIKey;

    $.ajax({
      url: weatherCSQueryURL,
      method: "GET"
     }).done(function(response) {
       //$(".city").html("<h1>" + response.name + " Weather </h1>");
       $(".wind").html("<h1>" + response.name + "</h1>");
       //$(".humidity").html("Humidity: " + response.main.humidity);
       //var f_temp = 9/5*(response.main.temp-273)+32;
       //$(".temp").html("Temperature (F) " + Math.floor(f_temp));
       resolve(response.weather[0].id);
       });
    });
  };
```

now the function that DOES work:

```
function getWeatherWithGeo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    getGeoLocationGoogle()
      .then(function(response) {
          var lat = response.location.lat;
          var lon = response.location.lng;

          var weatherLLQueryURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + WeatherAPIKey;
          $.ajax({
              url: weatherLLQueryURL,
              method: "GET"
          }).done(function(response) {
              $(".wind").html("<h1>" + response.name + "</h1>");
              resolve(response.weather[0].id);
          });
        })
      })

    }
```

I can't seem to find the difference, why one would work while the other doesn't. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: what is the error is it by any chance related to the lat and log? Also I suggest you create lat and log from available methods within js.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal the error is "GET {the url for the apil is here} 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @DeepakJha the second function (the one that uses lat and log) works fine, it's the first function that doesn't work.  It gives a 404 for the Get request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct URL should be:

```
var weatherCSQueryURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + "&appid=" + WeatherAPIKey;
```

The `=` sign after the location was asking for another value and telling the ajax request that location would be a parm.

Comment: Yes perfect, thank you! They'll let me accept your answer in 2 minutes.